# Gateway Timeout when trying to pay via PayPal or Stripe in Woocommerce. How to fix error?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I get a Gateway Timeout error when I try to pay via PayPal or Stripe in Woocommerce. Tried to disable plugins - it did not help. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: `### WordPress Environment ###

Home URL: https://www.qhhtofficial.com
Site URL: https://www.qhhtofficial.com
WC Version: 3.2.6
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 4.9.1
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 768 MB
WP Debug Mode: ✔
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_US

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache
PHP Version: 7.0.26
PHP Post Max Size: 256 MB
PHP Time Limit: 500
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.57.0
OpenSSL/1.0.2m`

Comment: Could be plenty of reasons to cause gateway timeout - https://kinsta.com/blog/504-gateway-timeout/

Comment: What does your php/event log file show? Anything in the gateway log file? Enable debugging and try again for the gateway log file, then send it without critical credentials or info

Comment: @GeekNinja only this in debug.log file - `[07-Jan-2018 17:30:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/qhhtofficial/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/lib/wordfenceClass.php on line 790`. Where I can find gateway log file on server or how to swich it on?

Comment: There should be a path in the paypal plugin settings

Comment: @GeekNinja the payment goes through in the log, and the subscription is extended, but I can not yet receive a message that the payment was successful on checkout page